# How to preserve the original data frame after creating a 'numerized' version of it via cat.codes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame called `df`, which has certain columns with object values. I want to turn those into categorical columns by using the following for loop:

```
df_numerized = df
for col in df_numerized.columns:
    if df_numerized[col].dtype == 'object':
        df_numerized[col] = df_numerized[col].astype('category')
        df_numerized[col] = df_numerized[col].cat.codes
```

Now when I call `df_numerized` I get what I want, but this has also changed the original data frame `df` in a similar way. How can I run my code without 'numerizing' the original data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df_numerized` is simply a named reference to `df`, so when you update `df_numerized` the change will be propagated to `df`, to prevent this you can create a copy of `df` for e.g you can do `df_numerized = df.copy()`. However, there is more consice approach using [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object')
df_numerized = df.assign(**cols.apply(lambda s: s.factorize(sort=True)[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure: does .factorize always assign the same values to the columns' members that cat.codes does? Or is it just another way of doing the numerization? In general I'd appreciate it if you can say a bit or lead me towards a source on the comparison of these two.

Comment: @qk11 Yes, `factorize` with `sort=True` is technically similar to doing `.cat.codes`. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Please strat with usage of the `copy` method.

`df_numerized = df.copy()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html